# R data.table update by condition based on current row

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data.table, insert-update

I have a `data.table` where each row corresponds to a set with assigned `mass`. Sometimes, the mass assigned is (`NA`). I would like to update it by the minimum of numerical masses assigned to its subsets.

The set is encoded by `set` column (bit notation represented as an integer). The `imprint` column is a bitmap representation of the set for visual control of this example. `N` stands for the cardinality of the set.

```
dt <- data.table(id.fe = 1:15, set = c(1,2,4,8,3,5,9,6,10,12,7,11,13,14,15), imprint = c('0001','0010','0100','1000','0011','0101','1001','0110','1010','1100','0111','1011','1101','1110','1111'), N = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4),  mass = c(0.4,1,1,0,0.3,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

    id.fe set imprint N mass
 1:     1   1    0001 1  0.4
 2:     2   2    0010 1  1.0
 3:     3   4    0100 1  1.0
 4:     4   8    1000 1  0.0
 5:     5   3    0011 2  0.3
 6:     6   5    0101 2   NA
 7:     7   9    1001 2   NA
 8:     8   6    0110 2   NA
 9:     9  10    1010 2   NA
10:    10  12    1100 2  0.0
11:    11   7    0111 3   NA
12:    12  11    1011 3   NA
13:    13  13    1101 3   NA
14:    14  14    1110 3   NA
15:    15  15    1111 4   NA
```

I.e. in the case of set `id.fe==6` with two elements, we have assigned mass `NA` and we would like to replace it by minimum mass of its subsets - i.e. sets `id.fe == 1` and `id.fe == 3` which is `0.4`. For illustration, I store it in a new column `newMass`.

So far I do it in a `for` loop: Note that the condition `bitwAnd(set, setId) == set, ]$mass)]` guarantees that set is a subset of idSet. The other two conditions `N < NId` and `!is.na(mass)`are not necessary - I hope it will speed up the calculations.

```
for(id in dt[is.na(mass),id.fe]) {
  idSet <- dt[id.fe == id, set]
  idN <- dt[id.fe == id, N]
  dt[id.fe == id, newMass := min(dt[N < idN & !is.na(mass) & bitwAnd(set, idSet) == set, ]$mass)]
}

dt[]
    id.fe set imprint N mass newMass
 1:     1   1    0001 1  0.4      NA
 2:     2   2    0010 1  1.0      NA
 3:     3   4    0100 1  1.0      NA
 4:     4   8    1000 1  0.0      NA
 5:     5   3    0011 2  0.3      NA
 6:     6   5    0101 2   NA     0.4
 7:     7   9    1001 2   NA     0.0
 8:     8   6    0110 2   NA     1.0
 9:     9  10    1010 2   NA     0.0
10:    10  12    1100 2  0.0      NA
11:    11   7    0111 3   NA     0.3
12:    12  11    1011 3   NA     0.0
13:    13  13    1101 3   NA     0.0
14:    14  14    1110 3   NA     0.0
15:    15  15    1111 4   NA     0.0
```

Is there any possibility to remove the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try this sequence.

1. Pre-determine all sets' subsets:

   ```r
   allsets <- CJ(
       otherset = unique(dt[, set]), set = unique(dt[, set])
     )[bitwAnd(set, otherset) == otherset & set != otherset,]
   allsets[set == 5,]
   #        b   set
   #    <num> <num>
   # 1:     1     5
   # 2:     4     5
   ```
2. Calculate and summarize each `set`'s min of subset masses:

   ```r
   allsets[dt, mass := i.mass, on = .(otherset == set)]
   newmasses <- allsets[, .(newmass = min(mass, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(set)]
   newmasses
   #       set newmass
   #     <num>   <num>
   #  1:     3     0.4
   #  2:     5     0.4
   #  3:     7     0.3
   #  4:     9     0.0
   #  5:    11     0.0
   #  6:    13     0.0
   #  7:    15     0.0
   #  8:     6     1.0
   #  9:    10     0.0
   # 10:    14     0.0
   # 11:    12     0.0
   ```
3. Join and coalesce:

   ```r
   dt[newmasses, newmass := i.newmass, on = .(set)
     ][, mass := fcoalesce(mass, newmass)][, newmass := NULL]
   #     id.fe   set imprint     N  mass
   #     <int> <num>  <char> <num> <num>
   #  1:     1     1    0001     1   0.4
   #  2:     2     2    0010     1   1.0
   #  3:     3     4    0100     1   1.0
   #  4:     4     8    1000     1   0.0
   #  5:     5     3    0011     2   0.3
   #  6:     6     5    0101     2   0.4
   #  7:     7     9    1001     2   0.0
   #  8:     8     6    0110     2   1.0
   #  9:     9    10    1010     2   0.0
   # 10:    10    12    1100     2   0.0
   # 11:    11     7    0111     3   0.3
   # 12:    12    11    1011     3   0.0
   # 13:    13    13    1101     3   0.0
   # 14:    14    14    1110     3   0.0
   # 15:    15    15    1111     4   0.0
   ```